# Shape won't scale

Tags: java

Whenever I try to scale the shape, nothing happens and then the console stops responding to input.
Here is the set scale command:

```
case 7: do
                         {
                            System.out.println("\nEnter scale factor");
                            scale=input.nextDouble();
                         }
                         while(scale<0);
                         Shape.setScaleFactor(scale);
                         break;
```

Here is the scale shape command

```
 case 4: for(i=0; i<s.length; i++)
                         {
                            if(s[i]!=null)
                            {
                              s[i].scaleShape();
                            }
                         }
                         break;
```

Here is the main method variables:

```
int i=0;
        int m=0;
        double scale;
        boolean exit=false;
        Shape[] s = new Shape[10];
```

Here are all the relevant methods in the shape class;

```
private static double scaleFactor;
public static double getScaleFactor()
    {

        return scaleFactor;
    }
    //Set ScaleFactor
    public static void setScaleFactor(double x)
    {

        scaleFactor=x;
    }
```

Here is the scaleshape method in the rectangle subclass

```
private double base;
    private double height;   
@Override public void scaleShape()
    {
        base=base*getScaleFactor(); height=height*getScaleFactor();

    }

        public abstract void scaleShape();
```

Here is the set scale method in the circle class:

```
private final double pi = Math.PI;
    private double radius;
 @Override public void scaleShape()
    {
         radius*=getScaleFactor();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your problem is here:

```
do
{
    System.out.println("\nEnter scale factor");
    scale = input.nextDouble();
}
while(scale < 0);
```

What happens if you add some logging?

```
do
{
    System.out.println("\nEnter scale factor");
    scale = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Scale entered was: " + scale);
    System.out.println("Is scale < 0? " + (scale < 0));
}
while(scale < 0);
```

If you don't get what you're expecting, it might be worthwhile to read in a `String` instead just to see what input you're actually getting. You can always read a String, log it, then use [`Double.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) to convert it.

Another possibility is that it's working, but you never reset `scale` and this is in some sort of loop, so it just continues scaling the shape forever but never stops to ask for input again.

Comment: @redelman431 Your comment seems to show that it's working fine, but you marked this as accepted. Did you figure out what was wrong?